# Get more than 1 id to new inserted row

Tags: sql-server

I have this data.

[image: click to see image]

I want to duplicate data like a picture above with stored procedure.

First thing I do is copying two rows in the first table. How can I get 2 (two) 'iId' in the first table to create 2 (two) rows in the second table and put those 'iId' into 'iId_JTS-Rule_RulePricingGroup' like the picture above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `OUTPUT` clause with `INSERT`

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1(
  ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  Title varchar(10)
)

CREATE TABLE #Table2(
  ID int,
  Title varchar(10)
)


DECLARE @NewIDs TABLE(ID int)


INSERT #Table1(Title)
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @NewIDs(ID) -- save new IDs
VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C')


INSERT #Table2(ID,Title)
SELECT ID,Title
FROM #Table1
WHERE ID IN(SELECT ID FROM @NewIDs) -- use new IDs


DROP TABLE #Table1
DROP TABLE #Table2
```